# Why Coded UI Test Automation is important?

Tags: c#

I am new to the subject of Testing an app. It's been a few days starting surfing over the Internet to find out some useful tutorials. Honestly, I could just found some good videos
giving me a big picture about how to make some Coded UI Test Automation, A Database Unit Test and also Unit testing using MS Visual Studio 2010. 
But still there are lots of questions on my mind. For example, an automation of CUIT is just
recording what I did as running the application and testing on my own. So what..?
It just records my actions. This is actually me who tests the application traditionally.
I know and sure that there must be some reason I'm not aware of!
Can anyone please explain to me how a automated Coded UI Test is to help me?
On the other hand, there is a similar question about Database Unit Testing.
I've found a video tutorial on YouTube explaining an example of this. It just simply checks
if a stored procedure is to work properly! Obviously, as I'm running my application (Pressing F5) I will simply understand if an Insert SP is working perfectly or not!
Thus again, I can't get what the role of Database Unit Testing is?
I will appreciate in advance if anyone could give me an idea or any useful link.
Thank you,

Comment: Yes, it just records what you do, so you're testing the application. But you only have to test it once - after that, it's able to run on its own. The benefits of this over having to test yourself - and to make sure you're doing the same thing every time - should be obvious.

Comment: Well.. It sounds reasonable Chris! Thanks a lot

Comment: Database unit testing allows you to check the sp has correct value it executes correctly or not , it assert the actual result== expected result , advantage of unit test, u can test in milliseconds . so u can make sure ur code is Robust. Test driven development has advantages Write testcase and write minimum code to pass it [Unit test Advantage](http://blog.typemock.com/2012/10/22/10-benefits-of-unit-testing) , [Getting started with unit test](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197662/Unit-Testing-Getting-Started-with-NUnit)

Answer (score 2):

One of the big advantages to having automated tests is that it gives you the confidence to change and fix things and to add features without worrying about the possibility that something will break, or that there will be unexpected side effects. It's easy and cheap to run pre-coded tests after every change, so you can make even the riskiest changes even late in the development cycle and still be confident that your application is still good.

Another advantage is this: suppose that some new code you write *does* break or change some existing functionality. Then, you have an easy way to discover a list exactly what has changed (just run the automated tests and see the results!), and then you can reason about these changes, and classify them as either bugs, actually desired side effects/changes, etc. Otherwise, development quickly becomes a mess of "one step forward, two steps back" - every checkin might fix one problem and introduce two new ones. Even if the developer is aware of the two new problems (which isn't always the case), despite best intentions they will simply forget to address these new problems later on.

You say that you can "just run an SP" or "just run" the UI yourself. But that doesn't scale... Again, ideally you'd want to be able to run 1000s of tests automatically after every change at no cost to you, which means they have to be automated. Also, you say that you know whether an SP is working just by running the application... but as your database and your application get more and more complex, it becomes less and less obvious what you have to do in your application to actually test your database properly. Also, what if later you need to create a 2nd application that uses the same database? (e.g. you now have a website, and later need to create some command-line tool for admins).

All this becomes much more important when there are multiple people working on the same piece of code, for obvious reasons. Without good automated test coverage, complicated pieces of code quickly become one-person's-domain ("Don't touch that code without talking to Joe!").

Of course, this does not mean that you should blindly apply all available test technologies to all projects, especially relatively "expensive" oves like CUIT (it's possibly expensive because if your UI changes a lot during the course of a project, this type of test can be harder to update). Instead, you should do a proper assessment of the real risk areas in your project (the "bug farms" if you will), and the right time in the cycle to introduce each type of testing - i.e. have an actual Test Plan. This last paragraph is my opinion, obviously there are different approaches to selecting what/how/when to test.

Comment: Dear Eugene, Now I can feel a little better about the issue! You just gave me a clear and complete answer. By now, I think need to find out the real risk areas in my project. But as I'm developing under 3-tier structure, You know.. I was thinking if I do Unit Testing for BLL, Database Unit testing for DAl and CUIT for PL, may be a good idea. But Anyway I thank you again Eugene!

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the note about the testing software recording your actions, this can be quite handy when trying to replicate a bug particularly when you first start writing the tests.

Like Eugene noted that when you get more than one coder things get more complicated, I would also like to add that when the software has to interact with other components (e.g. a server, other software packages) it gets very complicated very quickly. It is not always a safe bet to assume the other component is perfect. So the idea of automating your tests is that whilst you keep writing the software you can test against everything done before without you needing to do any work. For example I write a program that connects using Bluetooth but I add WiFi, I could use most (If not all) of those Bluetooth test cases against the Wifi. In a UI example imagine you add a new button which in the process you accidentally break an old button, if you have 10 buttons and it has no relation to the new button so you don't bother manually testing it but an automated test suite would pick it up straight away.

If you need more justification about testing I would highly suggest reading [Continuous Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380) which demonstrates why you should test and the benefits as well as giving examples on how to go about it. It also has some examples about DB testing!

I hope this helps, I am also new to testing but have learnt a lot in a short period.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I saw this, but it sums up unit testing very well.

"A well written unit test cannot find a bug...  But it sure as heck can find a regression"